# pg: 172-175 Multiple Interfaces, Stroustrup, C++ Programming Language, 3E

Tags: c++

I am having difficulty making any sense of this! What is he trying to say in
all this?

Page 172-173, does he create a SINGLE namespace with two interfaces (Parser, 
Parser-prime). Does he then stick each interface in a different header file 
(parser-implementer.h and parser-user.h). The parser-user.h has the smaller 
namespace definition and parser-implementer.h has the larger (implementer) 
namespace definitions. But then why does he say that: "compiler doesn't have sufficient information to check the consistency of the two definitions of the namespace."?? If the actual implementation is in: parser-crud.c, he should: `#include <parser-implementer>` that way the compiler would guarantee that the
C-definitions matched the declarations in the header.. of course parser-user.h
would not be checked.. is this what he's saying??

Then on pg:174(lower half), how is Parser_interface dependent on Parser::expr?? 
What exactly is he doing here???? Is he doing:

```
#include <parser-implementer.h>  // this gets namespace Parser into scope
namespace Parser_interface {
    using Parser::expr;
}
```

pg 175 (top line) How exactly is the driver "vulnerable" to any change in the Parser_interface interface????

I don't understand anything after that either (till page 176 top).. could 
someone explain in terms of header files, #include, and make-dependencies??

Can you have two:

```
namespace FOO { bar };
namespace FOO { baz };
```

definitions 
within one header file??

Comment: thanks for the edit inserting code's driving me nuts

Comment: Why are people voting for closing this? Asking something about a well-known book is not "too localized".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the namespaces. So what you must understand is that if you have 2 header file class Cube_impl.h and Cube.h They both can have

```
namespace Cube { ... }
```

The namespace is unique and will be define once. So he is not declaring 2 namespaces of the same name, but he is using the same namespace twice. Thus, everything that is written inside this namespace will be part of it. You can use the namespace in multiples other class if it suits you. It can usually be accessed like that

```
Cube::FunctionName
```

---

Concerning the use of "user" interface and "implementer" interface.

This is a neat thing professional often use when they want to hide implementation to the user. They create a first header file that will contains all the public members/functions for the user (e.g. Cube.h). Then, they will create another header file for the "implementation" (e.g. Cube_impl.h) where the protected and private members/functions will be declared.

The benefits is that you can later on change Cube_impl.h without affecting the user since they don't even know about the code present there.

---

I didn't read the book you are referring to, but I hope this will answer your question.

Regards

Comment: thanks! yeah that was very helpful! that whole section in Stroustrup is expressed in a very obscure manner.

Comment: @paleywiener Cool, glad it helped you. Please mark the question as Answered so other people won't spend time trying to look for another answer :)